# VBA / VSTO > Powerpoint > Hide Secondary Context Menu

Tags: vba, powerpoint, vsto

I have written a VSTO addin for Poweproint.

I am able to hide/disable most existing context menu buttons using the CustomUI  XML config.

But cannot find how to access the secondary context menu (see below).

Not the whole thing. Just the top part (Style/Crop/New Comment)

What is the idMso for the mini context menu?

Ideally I would like to hide the mini context menu.

[image]

Comment: The context menu name you're looking for depends on the context in which it appears. What are you doing on-screen when this appears. In case you don't have the most recent version of the control ID help files, here's a link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745

Comment: It is the picture context menu. I am using idMso="ContextMenuPicture" to access the bottom buttons successfully.

But this does not work for the top section (style/crop/New Comment)